How long does it really take for the Voivodeship in Wroclaw Poland to issue an EU blue card?
I started working for a company in Wroclaw after an initial 3 month trial period on a business visa during June - August this year. I decided to take the job, and have been working remotely (from my home country, South Africa) for the past few months. My company applied for a work permit, but it's taking ridiculously long. We were told approximately 15 days, but it has been almost 2 months since the submission.
The company is in urgent need of my physical presence there, so we would prefer to not wait a whole year for this. We decided to apply for another business visa for 90 days so I can apply for an EU blue card (apparently it has to be applied for in person), and then work a bit whilst I wait for it. Does anyone know how long the processing really takes? I am finding lots of different answers online. I just don't want to end up waiting ridiculously long for this as well!

Ridiculously long processing time are “normal” in immigration matters. I don't know about Wroclaw specifically (so no answer) but 3 months does not seem out of the ordinary for a Blue Card in other member states, other types of long-stay visas or residence permits often take longer. The deadline set by the directive is 90 days (unless the employer is already recognized) so two months might even be within the rules.
